# Typing Persian (Farsi) replaces some characters with dashes

Tags: libreoffice

I have already installed all of things that are suggested to type Persian better but still it doesn't work as expected.

Libreoffice replaces some letters with a dash `-` or an underscore `_`.

For example, this is what I typed: الان

And this is what I saw on the screen: الا_ن

Comment: Could you please list the things you already tried?

Comment: Do you only experience this problem in LibreOffice? What happens in Gedit, Firefox and the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why My question removed ? My Problem is fixed By this solution :

1. Open Libre-office
2. go to Tools>Options>Language settings>Languages
3. change Locate setting to Farsi
4. then Change CTL to Farsi
5. this problem is fixed . Enjoy!

Please don't Delete Questions !